# difference between $R^2$ and $C$ in terms of point set topological properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm studying real analysis and complex analysis, also studying topological properties  of sets in both real as well as complex analysis like the open set, closed set, interior point, the boundary point etc
I'm curious about Is there any difference between these topological properties?

Comment: They have identical topological properties because $(x,y) \to x+iy$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: okay, I also believe that is true but I don't  this concept so really thanks,

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that's a circular argument. For a map to be a homeomorphism you need topologies on both sides of the map to begin with.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Also by this fact we can imagine any function in $R^2$  as $C$  and vice-versa, and talk about continuity and differentiability of such function.

Comment: Homeomorphism don't preserve differentiability.

Comment: if I'm not wrong, we can define a function like $f(x,y)=x$ is differentiable in $R^2$ but not in $C$ as its corresponding complex function $f(z)=(z+\bar{z})/2$ is non differentiable.

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy explained, $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb C$ (with their standard topologies) have the same topological properties because they are homeomorphic. Differentiability is not a topological concept.

Comment: These are simply two different notions of differentiability you are thinking of. One is real differentiability, whereas the other is complex differentiability. The notion of real differentiability on $\mathbb{C}$ is the same as the notion of real differentiability of $\mathbb{R}^2$ under this homeomorphism (in fancier terms, it is a diffeomorphism between these smooth manifolds - and real differentiability is a notion only depending on the structure as a smooth manifold). Complex differentiability is simply a different concept (which leads to the notion of a complex manifold).

Comment: @AndreasBlass  sir, I know differentiability is not topological property but I just wanted to explore more $R^2$ and $C$ this homeomorphism and improve my understanding of differentiability also.

Answer (score 4):

The complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is typically constructed as $\mathbb{R}^2$ with additional vector multiplication. With that setup the topology/metric/norm on $\mathbb{C}$ is defined to be the one from $\mathbb{R}^2$ (unless explicitly stated otherwise). And thus $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have exactly the same topology/metric/norm.